# Conditional redirection in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, next.js

Is it possible to conditionally redirect a user to another Url based on cookie value?
I know I can inspect cookie on a server & then redirect.
But what should I do if a user came through `Link`. (I can't use Route.push because it's undefined on the server)
Is there any way to use Router only on the browser?

I know at least one way to do this: to create simple `button` and add Router push & check cookies inside `onClick` handler, but is it a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 24):

you can check if user has accessed the page via server or client side.
and after that you can conditionally redirect with the proper tool.
`getInitialProps` function gets a `ctx` object. you can check whether its on server or client like this:

```
import Router from 'next/router'

export default class Browse extends Component {

    static async getInitialProps (ctx) {
        if (ctx && ctx.req) {
            console.log('server side')
            ctx.res.writeHead(302, {Location: `/`})
            ctx.res.end()
        } else {
            console.log('client side')
            Router.push(`/`)
        }
...
```

Comment: Avoid 301 unless you're really sure. Use 302 for temporary moves.